# How to find and replace using a regular expression to remove an attribute in a specific xml tag

Tags: regex, xml

I am working with an xml file with a couple iterations of:

```
<Create key="*insert_characters*">
```

I would like to have all of these tags to just read:

```
<Create>
```

I pretty much want to remove all attributes with only the Create element, I have elements with attributes but wish to keep them. I apologize but I am not too familiar with regular expressions and hope this question hasn't been answered already. I am trying to use the Regular Expression search mode on notepad++.

Any thoughts or opinions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

replace all `<([c|C]reate)[^>]*>` by `<\1>`

Comment: your code gets rid of the attributes in the xml tag but how do i make it get rid of the attributes for the "Create" element specifically? I have some other tags that I wish to keep the attributes in. Sorry if my question was not clear, I'll edit the question.

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. i was told to not add these type of comments but wanted to express my thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import re
  x='<Create key="*insert_characters*">'
  print re.sub(r"<Create .*",r"<Create>",x)



   Output:<Create>
```